# Monotonicity of min-entropy

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Let $Z^t = (Y_1,\ldots,Y_t)$ be a sequence of random variables each taking values in $Y$. The random variables are not necessarily i.i.d but we know the joint distributions. i.e for every $z = (z_1,...,z_t)$ we know $P^{Z^t}(z)$

The min-entropy of a random variable $X$ is defined as $-\log_2(\max P(x) )$ for x in the value set of $X$.

Finally, we define a sequence of values $H^\infty(t) =  -\log_2(\max P^{Z^t}(z))$ for $Z^t$ defined as above.

How can we show that $H^\infty(t)$  is monotonically increasing in t? i.e for $t' \geq t$ it is the case that $H^\infty(t') \geq H^\infty(t)$.

What I am trying without success is to show that $\max P^{Z^t}(z^t) \geq \max P^{Z^{t'}}(z^{t'})$ where $t \leq t'$.

Comment: If $Y$ is not IID, then your equation for $H^\infty$ doesn't apply.  It's not that easy and a common mistake. It will over estimate the entropy in some weird proportion to the auto correlation. Consider, if there's a close but diminishing relationship over many $n$ in $Y_n$, what's $y$ exactly? This equation only applies to IID variables.

Comment: Sorry the notation is a bit wonky... So in this case, $Y$ is the range of the random variables, the tuple $(Y_1,...,Y_t)$ would be a random variable with range $Y^t$ for which we know the joint distribution. Finally $y$ is an element of $Y^t$. In which case the min-entropy as written should be well defined.. I hope :)

Comment: But I am certain that $y \in Y$. I will edit the notation to make it clearer. Thanks and sorry to the terrible formulation :)

Comment: I'm saying that in the specific case of non IID data as you suggest, $H^\infty(t) \neq  -\log_2(\max P(y))$ as long as $y \in Y$.  This equation (as well as $H^{sh}$) only applies to IID variables. The real $H^\infty$ will be lower, perhaps much lower depending on the strength of the auto correlation.  It's common to drop the non IID assumption in these situations. Otherwise you end up in a world of Markov chains and pains.

Comment: I have modified the question to make it clearer, have a look. So I my case i.i.d is not really a concern my random variables are just normal random variables defined over a 'tuple space' so to say. In which case even Shanon entropy applies(checking on Wikipedia). Am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make it slightly simpler by proving the case of two variables with no tuple indexing to clutter it up.  Fix two random variables $X$ and $Y$.  Is $H_\infty[X] \leq H_\infty[(X, Y)]$?

For each $x$, we have $$\Pr[X = x] = \sum_y \Pr[X = x, Y = y].$$  Note that since probability masses are always positive, $\max \Pr[\cdots] \leq \sum \Pr[\cdots]$; then the sense will get reversed because $p \mapsto -\log p$ is a decreasing function:

\begin{align}
  H_\infty[X]
  &= -\log \max_x \Pr[X = x] \\
  &= -\log \max_x \sum_y \Pr[X = x, Y = y] \\
  &\leq -\log \max_x \max_y \Pr[X = x, Y = y] \\
  &= -\log \max_{x,y} \Pr[X = x, Y = y] \\
  &= H_\infty[(X, Y)].
\end{align}

Then to prove that $t \mapsto H_\infty[(Z_1, \dots, Z_t)]$ is increasing, take $X = (Z_1, \dots, Z_t)$ and $Y = Z_{t+1}$.

Comment: Accepted Answer for simplicity, clarity and didactic value. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution.

Let $z = (z_1,\ldots,z_{t+1})$ be the value that maximizes $P^{Z^{t+1}}[\cdot]$ and the probability is $Pz$. Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_t)$ the value that maximizes $P^{Z^{t}}[\cdot]$ and the probability is $P_x$; finally let $Py = \sum_{l \in Y} Pr[(z_1,\ldots, z_t,l)]$. $Py$ is then the probability of $y = (z_1,\ldots,z_t)$ i.e the first $t$ elements of $z$.

It follows then that $P_z \leq P_y \leq P_x$.

Which shows that $H^\infty(t)$ is monotonically increasing.